# make a global condition break

Tags: python, variables, conditional-statements, break

allow me to preface this by saying that i am learning python on my own as part of my own curiosity, and i was recommended a free online computer science course that is publicly available, so i apologize if i am using terms incorrectly.

i have seen questions regarding this particular problem on here before - but i have a separate question from them and did not want to hijack those threads. the question:

"a substring is any consecutive sequence of characters inside another string. The same substring may occur several times inside the same string: for example "assesses" has the substring "sses" 2 times, and "trans-Panamanian banana" has the substring "an" 6 times. Write a program that takes two lines of input, we call the first needle and the second haystack. Print the number of times that needle occurs as a substring of haystack."

my solution (which works) is:

```
first = str(input())
second = str(input())

count = 0
location = 0
while location < len(second):
   if location == 0:
      location = str.find(second,first,0)
      if location < 0:
         break
      count = count + 1                          
   location = str.find(second,first,location +1)   
   if location < 0:
      break
   count = count + 1
print(count)
```

if you notice, i have on two separate occasions made the if statement that if location is less than 0, to break. is there some way to make this a 'global' condition so i do not have repetitive code? i imagine efficiency becomes paramount with increasing program sophistication so i am trying to develop good practice now.

how would python gurus optimize this code or am i just being too nitpicky?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with breaking at two separate junctions.

Comment: That being said, an easy way to do a complete loop exit is to encapsulate your code in a function and use return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out regular expressions, python's `re` module (http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). For example,

```
import re
first = str(input())
second = str(input())
regex = first[:-1] + '(?=' + first[-1] + ')'
print(len(re.findall(regex, second)))
```

Comment: While regular expressions are usually good, the `findall` method is not right for this problem. Try your code with the "assesses" example and it will only see one match. The reason is that some of the matches may be overlapping, which regular expressions usually don't allow.

Comment: @Blckknght Good call. I'll edit it to include a lookahead (though that's a little hack-y).

Comment: To clarify what these comments are about for future readers, my original answer effectively had `regex=first` instead of the current regex, which led to the issue that Blckknght pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

I think Matthew and darshan have the best solution. I will just post a variation which is based on your solution:

```
first = str(input())
second = str(input())  

def count_needle(first, second):

        location = str.find(second,first)
        if location == -1:
                return 0 # none whatsoever
        else:
                count = 1
                while location < len(second):
                   location = str.find(second,first,location +1)   
                   if location < 0:
                      break
                   count = count + 1
        return count

print(count_needle(first, second))
```

Idea:

- use function to structure the code when appropriate
- initialise the variable `location` before entering the while loop save you from checking location < 0 multiple times

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Matthew Adams the best way to do it is using python'd re module [Python re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

For your case the solution would look something like this:

```
import re

def find_needle_in_heystack(needle, heystack):
  return len(re.findall(needle, heystack))
```

Since you are learning python, best way would be to use 'DRY' [Don't Repeat Yourself] mantra. There are lots of python utilities that you can use for many similar situation.

For a quick overview of few very important python modules you can go through this class:

[Google Python Class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/)

which should only take you a day.

Comment: As I mentioned on Matthew Adams' answer, `findall` won't work for overlapping matches.

Answer (score 0):

even your aproach could be imo simplified (which uses the fact, that find returns -1, while you aks it to search from non existent offset):

```
>>> x = 'xoxoxo'
>>> start = x.find('o')
>>> indexes = []
>>> while start > -1:
...     indexes.append(start)
...     start = x.find('o',start+1)
>>> indexes
[1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
needle = "ss"
haystack = "ssi lass 2 vecess estan ss."

print 'needle occurs %d times in haystack.' % haystack.count(needle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
first = str(input())
second = str(input())
x=len(first)
counter=0
for i in range(0,len(second)):
   if first==second[i:(x+i)]:
      counter=counter+1
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

```
needle=input()
haystack=input()
counter=0
for i in range(0,len(haystack)):
  if(haystack[i:len(needle)+i]!=needle):
     continue
  counter=counter+1
print(counter)
```